# Rails: Changing form method to PATCH in javascript sends a GET request on form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which by default is a `POST`. On change of a drop down, I want to change the form method to `PATCH` and its action to something else and submit the form.

erb:

```
<%= form_for @booking, :url => admin_events_bookings_path, :html => { :class => 'smart-form', :id => 'mainForm', :data => { :change_event_path => change_event_admin_events_bookings_path } } do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

HTML (rendered):

```
<form class="smart-form" id="mainForm" data-change-event-path="/admin/events/bookings/change_event" action="/admin/events/bookings" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="oC9bO0GVnMuc4UFnJLKDbTvaWEPLCKycmrsTJGWcHyYZ2QrYsVzbvP1pmMmqF/LIT3BepGCTWhZ0YZyPGsJUPg==">
...
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#booking_event_id').on('change', function(ev) {
    $('#mainForm').attr('action', $('#mainForm').data().changeEventPath) //this works, verified in browser
    $('#mainForm').attr('method', 'patch') //this works, verified in browser
    $('#mainForm')[0].submit()
})
```

However the request that reaches the server is a GET request. From the log:

```
Started GET "/admin/events/bookings/change_event?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=oizowirdfSiR%2BiUGIsZWe8PHSypUAItFK8Y39gwNtK4b2rkh2hQ6X%2FBy%2FKisYyfet21Nzf%2Bbfc%2FFHLhdc1P%2Ftg%3D%3D&ticket_type=priced&booking%5Bevent_id%5D=2"
```

Why does the form submit as a GET request? How can I make this work?

Comment: There is no such patch request in rails.
When you set method to `patch` rails add a hidden field say "method" in the form and that is used to know that it was a patch request.

Please try adding a hidden field in your form by javascript

Comment: I tried the same code for `put`. The result is the same.

Comment: have you tried adding hidden field?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The hidden field is `_method`.

Comment: glad I could help you. cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Setting+the+method):

> If the verb is not GET or POST, which are natively supported by HTML forms, the form will be set to POST and a hidden input called _method will carry the intended verb for the server to interpret.

So to change the verb, you only need to add a hidden field to the form named **_method** with the value **patch** or **put**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
```